# What is this zsh file generated unintentionally every time I use zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh

The file name is `zsh.<computer_name>.local.<random_numbers>`. In this case it is `zsh.macbook.local.754`. It started appearing after I moved all zsh files in the home directory to `~/dotfiles/zsh` and configured `.zshrc` and `.zshenv`. These files are appearing in `~/dotfiles/zsh`.

```bash
#files: 931 version: 5.8.1

_comps=(
'-' '_precommand'
'-array-value-' '_value'
'-assign-parameter-' '_assign'
'-brace-parameter-' '_brace_parameter'
'-command-' '_autocd'
'-command-line-' '_normal'
'-condition-' '_condition'
'-default-' '_default'
'-equal-' '_equal'
'-first-' '_first'
'-math-' '_math'
'-parameter-' '_parameter'
'-redirect-' '_redirect'
'-redirect-,-default-,-default-' '_files'
'-redirect-,<,bunzip2' '_bzip2'
'-redirect-,<,bzip2' '_bzip2'
'-redirect-,<,compress' '_compress'
'-redirect-,<,gunzip' '_gzip'
'-redirect-,<,gzip' '_gzip'
'-redirect-,<,uncompress' '_compress'
'-redirect-,<,unxz' '_xz'
'-redirect-,<,xz' '_xz'
'-redirect-,>,bzip2' '_bzip2'
'-redirect-,>,compress' '_compress'
'-redirect-,>,gzip' '_gzip'
'-redirect-,>,xz' '_xz'
'-subscript-' '_subscript'
'-tilde-' '_tilde'
'-value-' '_value'
'-value-,-default-,-command-' '_zargs'
'-value-,-default-,-default-' '_value'
'-value-,ADB_TRACE,-default-' '_adb'
'-value-,ANDROID_LOG_TAGS,-default-' '_adb'
'-value-,ANDROID_SERIAL,-default-' '_adb'
'-value-,ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK,-default-' '_ansible'
'-value-,ANT_ARGS,-default-' '_ant'
'-value-,CFLAGS,-default-' '_gcc'
'-value-,CPPFLAGS,-default-' '_gcc'
'-value-,CXXFLAGS,-default-' '_gcc'
'-value-,DISPLAY,-default-' '_x_display'
'-value-,GREP_OPTIONS,-default-' '_grep'



...



zle -C _bash_complete-word .complete-word _bash_completions
zle -C _bash_list-choices .list-choices _bash_completions
zle -C _complete_debug .complete-word _complete_debug
zle -C _complete_help .complete-word _complete_help
zle -C _complete_tag .complete-word _complete_tag
zle -C _correct_filename .complete-word _correct_filename
zle -C _correct_word .complete-word _correct_word

typeset -gUa _comp_assocs
_comp_assocs=( '' )
```

EDIT: The solution is to add this line.

```bash
compinit -d ${ZDOTDIR}/.zcompdump
```

Comment: It looks like it's saving the state of zsh completions.